# How can I convert characters into a bytes-like object for Python 3 Base64 encoding?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, encryption, base64

I have a function in Python 2 which encrypts a string into a Base64 encoded object.
When I run the same in Python 3 I get different output. Together with the following TypeError:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

How can I get a the correct bytes-like object in order to encode the string "hello world" into Base64?

```
    enc = []
    clear = "hello world"
    key = "1234567890"
    for i in range(len(clear)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc_c = chr((ord(clear[i]) + ord(key_c)) % 256)
        enc.append(enc_c)
    print ("enc:", enc)
    print (base64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc)))
```

Running this in Python 2, gives the following output:

> enc: ['\x99', '\x97', '\x9f', '\xa0', '\xa4', 'V', '\xae', '\xa7', '\xab', '\x9c', '\x95']

Base64 encoded: mZefoKRWrqernJU=

Running this in Python 3, gives different output for the encrypted list `enc` and the TypeError:

> enc: ['\x99', '\x97', '\x9f', '\xa0', '¤', 'V', '®', '§', '«', '\x9c', '\x95']

How can I get same the results running in Python3?

Comment: For Python3, one way is to take the encoded values for `clear` and `key` (`b'...'`), build `enc_c` as the sum of `clear[i]` and `key_c` modulo `256`, and convert the resulting list with `bytes(...)` into a bytes-like object that is Base64url encoded, see [online](https://paiza.io/projects/365t0ccrMrny3R_6I_U3mw).

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: [string encode/decode did work in Python2 but can't get it working in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622509/string-encode-decode-did-work-in-python2-but-cant-get-it-working-in-python3)

Comment: Topaco, thanks very much for this explanation and example code. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the explanation and example code provided by topaco, this is the working encoding function:

```
def encode(key, clear):
    enc = []
    bkey = key.encode()
    bclear = clear.encode()
    for i in range(len(bclear)):
        key_c = bkey[i % len(bkey)]
        enc_c = (bclear[i] + key_c) % 256
        enc.append(enc_c)
    encB64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(enc))  # convert list to bytes-like object
    print("base64 encoded:", encB64.decode())
    return encB64.decode()
```